# How to find the device path in mac (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ios, file, device

I am working in iPhone application, I have download a file from Dropbox to store iPhone device path like `"/Users/govindarajk/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/343cc44-024DF2-34qs34-4433243-csafsa42232/Documents/Example.txt"`, but i check this path in my Mac, the path file not shown it, How to find this path and Example.txt file? please help me

Thanks in Advance

I have to store a file this way:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Example.txt"];
    NSError *error;

    [self.restClient loadFile:@"/example/Example.txt" intoPath:filePath];

    if (filePath) { // check if file exists - if so load it:
        NSString *tempTextOut = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                             error:&error];
    }
```

Screen shot for your reference:

User/govindaraj/Library, the Library file not shown here:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Library` directory is hidden, you can go there by doing the following:
Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> when in finder.
Then a dialog will popup asking to open a directory, just type in `~/Library` and it should open the library directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this but folder cannot be found

Comment: Sorry made a typo in the / (should not be \ but / )

Comment: see above, i have attached screen shot for your reference.

Comment: See my comment about / and \, sorry again I made a typo.

Comment: I tried both of this / and \, but the same error comes in file not be found

Comment: sorry,sorry i got this, thank you so much for your help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open up Terminal and enter the following

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Then relaunch Finder from the Force Quit option on the Apple menu.

If you want to turn hidden files back on, the command is

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
```